# NoClassDefFoundError while deploying an application on WAS

Tags: java, web-applications, websphere

I am trying to deploy an application on WAS 6.1 Server.

However, I am getting the below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.Logger
at myPackage.myClass.<clinit>(myClass.java:40)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:194)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1328)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.loadBeanMetaData(EJSContainer.java:1756)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeOfHomes.loadBeanMetaData(HomeOfHomes.java:1073)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeRecord.getHomeAndInitialize(HomeRecord.java:454)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.getHomeWrapperCommon(EJSContainer.java:1322)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.getHomeInstance(EJSContainer.java:1231)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.startBean(EJSContainer.java:1217)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startBean(EJBContainerImpl.java:3385)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startModule(EJBContainerImpl.java:2589)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3719)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1304)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1165)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:587)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:832)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:950)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2131)
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:579)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:414)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:597)
... 22 more
```

In

```
Admin Console -> Servers -> Application Servers -> myServerName -> Java and Process Management -> Process Definition -> Java Virtual Machine -> ClassPath
```

I have an entry as below:

```
${MY_JARS}\log4j-1.2.15.jar
```

Where in 'Custom Properties' MY_JARS key contains value as the path to the log4j jar

I did server clean and restart, republish, redeploy the application umpteen number of times. But this error is not going.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `${MY_JARS}` that way, you need to define it in `Environment` > `WebSphere Variables`, not in `Custom Properties`.

However I'd caution you about adding log4j in that manner. I seem to recall log4j might not work correctly if a single jar is shared across multiple apps. I think we attempted using log4j as a Shared Library (probably the more recommended way of doing what you're trying to do, BTW), but ended up needing to deploy to each application's WEB-INF/lib instead.

Answer (score 1):

As dbreaux already pointed out you have to create environment variables with the correct scope. A custom property is available at runtime, but not for the server configuration level.

Within the WAS you can check what libraries are loaded. IIRC you have to click on the Application, afterwards on the Web Module and than you should be able to check the classloaders. If you open up the classloaders, you will see what libraries are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure log4j.jar is on the CLASSPATH of your application.For example; under WEB-INF\lib

Comment: But as explained above, it is present on the class path. Right ?

Comment: @NikunjChauhan Yes, log4j.jar need to be on your application CLASSPATH.